# Large float values are lost when inserted into SQL Server using Sequelize

Tags: sql-server, floating-point, sequelize.js, tedious, node-mssql

Whenever I try to insert a floating point number larger than ~50k using the sequelize ORM, the database gets populated with something else.

For this value `123456789.123456` I get this inserted `11186.78219`.

Some other colleagues have gotten different outputs, but close to `11186.78219` like `11177.782191683797`, for other inputs. I'm not sure what that hints at.

Everything works fine when I perform the same insert via the `node-mssql` client, which is also used by Sequelize internally

So I traced the execution path from the Sequelize's model's create statement, through `node-mssql`, through tedious, and up to the node.js network request libraries just to see that my initial input number was kept unchanged throughout.

After the request is sent, though, something happens and the database receives a different value.

Setting a large value directly on the database and retrieving it through Sequelize works fine, as well.

I created [this repo](https://github.com/firefueled/node-mssql-float-fail) to see if any of you can replicate it.

Edit: I guess I should clarify how I'm using Sequelize :)

This an example User model, and creation, that fails:

```
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    networth: {
        type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
        // none of these work
        // type: DataTypes.FLOAT(20, 5),
        // type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(20, 5),
        // type: DataTypes.DOUBLE,
    },
}, {
    timestamps: false,
});

User.create({ networth: 123456798.123456 });
```

This `node-mssql` example works, though:

```
await pool.request()
    .input('networth', sql.Float, float_value)
    .query(`insert into users (networth) values (@networth)`)
```

Edit 2: I grabbed some data from SQL Server Profiler showing the differences between the Sequelize and `node-mssql` calls:

node-mssql: `exec sp_executesql @statement=N'insert into users (networth) values (@networth)',@params=N'@networth float',@networth=123456798,123456`

Sequelize: `exec sp_executesql @statement=N'INSERT INTO [Users] ([networth]) OUTPUT INSERTED.* VALUES (@0);',@params=N'@0 numeric(30, 15)',@0=11186.782191684157440`

So the data does arrive broken...

Edit 3: I think I found the source of the problem and I opened an issue [here.](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/12086)

Comment: This probably needs to be bugged with Sequelize: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues

Comment: Yep. I've opened an issue with them https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/12086

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it is a bug on Sequelize v5 and [it is resolved](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/11962) on the master branch.
I plan to submit a PR to have it integrated into v5, as well.

Answer (score 0):

It repro's for me.  Ran the app, and captured the traffic in Profiler.  The app sent

```
exec sp_executesql @statement=N'INSERT INTO [Users] ([networth]) OUTPUT INSERTED.* VALUES (@0);',@params=N'@0 numeric(30, 15)',@0=11186.782191684157440
```

And after running the app, the Users table contained:

```
id          networth
----------- ----------------------
1           11186.7821916842
```

Comment: Thanks. It's very weird that I found no other mention of this on the web. I posted my second edit just as you did this.